# Angular2 terrible performance with ngFor assigning variable to "index"

Tags: angular

Consider the following 2d array:

```
myLabels = [[45, 56, 63],
            [31, 67, 27],
            [89, 23, 61]]
```

Now in a template, iterate over this array like:

```
<template ngFor let-row_ [ngForOf]=myLabels let-i="index">
  <template ngFor let-labelid [ngForOf]=row_ let-j="index">
    ...
  </template>
</template>
```

When I increase my array to something larger, the performance tanks pretty hard. A modestly-sized 40x40 array takes almost 40 seconds to render with Chromium 50. It's a little faster on Firefox 47, but not by much.

If I eliminate the index assignments (`let-i="index"...`), then the performance is just fine

```
<template ngFor let-row_ [ngForOf]=myLabels>
  <template ngFor let-labelid [ngForOf]=row_>
    ...
  </template>
</template>
```

So, the question is, what can be done to mitigate this issue? Is there something that I'm missing regarding `ngFor`? Is there a different way?

Answer (score 0):

Did you try to change your change detection strategy to:  `ChangeDetectionStrategy.OnPush` ?

Also, consider creating Immutable arrays.(See immutable.js)

Check this article: http://jvandemo.com/how-i-optimized-minesweeper-using-angular-2-and-immutable-js-to-make-it-insanely-fast/